# How to add hover effects to slick slider arrow

Tags: javascript, css

```js
$('.hero-slider').slick({ 
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        dots:false,
        infinite: true
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="info-banner">
      <div class="hero-slider">
        <div class="info-slider-content" style="background-image: url(images/);">
          <div class="banner-content info-content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever </p>          
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-slider-content" style="background-image: url(images/);">
          <div class="banner-content info-content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-slider-content" style="background-image: url(images/);">
          <div class="banner-content info-content">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

I am trying to add a hover effect to my slick slider arrow like [this](https://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/#cl-effect-19). But the procedure followed here is totally different from the slider arrow and I am finding it very difficult to customize it. I have added previous and next arrows like

[image: this]

Help in any form would be great!

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle demo of your code.

Comment: please provide some html and your css code

Comment: Please read this - [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Code:

```css
nav a {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 15px 25px;
 outline: none;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 font-size: 1.35em;
}
.cl-effect-19 a {
 line-height: 2em;
 margin: 15px;
 -webkit-perspective: 800px;
 -moz-perspective: 800px;
 perspective: 800px;
 width: 200px;
}

.cl-effect-19 a span {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0 14px;
 background: #e35041;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, background 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, background 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s, background 0.4s;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;
 -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;
 transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;
}

.csstransforms3d .cl-effect-19 a span::before {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #b53a2d;
 content: attr(data-hover);
 -webkit-transition: background 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: background 0.4s;
 transition: background 0.4s;
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
 transform: rotateY(90deg);
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
 transform-origin: 0 50%;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.cl-effect-19 a:hover span,
.cl-effect-19 a:focus span {
 background: #b53a2d;
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
 transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}

.csstransforms3d .cl-effect-19 a:hover span::before,
.csstransforms3d .cl-effect-19 a:focus span::before {
 background: #ef5e50; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
<section class="color-5">
    <nav class="cl-effect-19" id="cl-effect-19">
     <a href="#cl-effect-19"><span data-hover="Ratatouille">Ratatouille</span></a>
    </nav>
   </section>
```

Comment: you have copy pasted the code which has been used by the reference link I have provided. I have already tried this and since slick slider is a plugin i cannot add span class to the button. The button is coming from the plugin. This is the reason i have posted this query here.

Comment: @Sanjeev  Sure. I have added a slider and have customised arrows using CSS. The method used in the reference link is by changing the structure of the button and adding a span class to it. But, in a slick slider, customising arrows/buttons is easy which I have done it. I am unable to bring this transition. So please help me on how to do this.

Comment: @Gabbax0 Sure. I have added a slider and have customised arrows using CSS. The method used in the reference link is by changing the structure of the button and adding a span class to it. But, in a slick slider, customising arrows/buttons is easy which I have done it. I am unable to bring this transition. So please help me on how to do this.

Comment: append "span" using jquery: $( "#cl-effect-19 a" ).append( $( "<span data-hover="Ratatouille">Ratatouille</span>" ) );